# HomeController not found. You need to call Get.put(HomeController()) or Get.lazyPut(()=>HomeController())

Tags: flutter, dart, controller, flutter-getx

I made a todo app using `Getx` package. I also created a login page and I want to display the login page only one time but when I try to do this I a got error

> "HomeController" not found. You need to call `Get.put(HomeController())` or `Get.lazyPut(()=>HomeController())`.

this is my binding

```
class HomeBinding implements Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut(() => HomeController(
          taskRepository: TaskRepository(
            taskProvider: TaskProvider(),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

this is my main.dart

```
int? isViewed;

void main() async {
  await GetStorage.init();
  await Get.putAsync(() => StorageService().init());
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await ScreenUtil.ensureScreenSize();
  await GetStorage.init();
  await Get.putAsync(() => StorageService().init());

  LicenseRegistry.addLicense(() async* {
    final license = await rootBundle.loadString('google_fonts/OFL.txt');
    yield LicenseEntryWithLineBreaks(['google_fonts'], license);
  });
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  isViewed = prefs.getInt('login');

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends GetView<HomeController> {
  const MyApp({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
        SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent));
    return ScreenUtilInit(
        designSize: const Size(360, 800),
        minTextAdapt: true,
        splitScreenMode: true,
        builder: (context, child) {
          return GetMaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: 'Flutter Demo',
            theme: Themes.light,
            darkTheme: Themes.dark,
            themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
            home: isViewed != 0 ? Login() : Report(),
            initialBinding: HomeBinding(),
            builder: EasyLoading.init(),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4AiV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `HomeBinding` in `getPages` array of `GetMaterialApp`.

Also apply below modifications in below scope

```
GetMaterialApp(
 // initialBinding: HomeBinding(),   ====>> Remove this line

 initialRoute: '/home',  // ====>> Add this line
 getPages: [
    GetPage(
      name: "/home",
      page: () => const HomeScreen(),
      binding: HomeBinding(),
    ),
   //  ====>> Add other pages like home
 ]

);
```

Comment: can you please further define it.... Yes your method works but my login screen is appearing after restarting app i want to make it one time screen

Comment: Try to read document about getx middleware. You need to make kind of authGuard.